# LINQ many-to-many relationships: Solution?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

LINQ so far has been remarkably elegant, but to perform basic m2m queries it offers no solution I can imediately see.

What's worse is that while it works for any other table relationship, LINQ is not giving me an association in the class structure for my m2m table.

So I can do things like

```
artwork.artists.where(...)
//or
artist.Artworks.add(artwork)
```

but I can't do

```
artwork.artowrks_subjects.tagSubjects.where(...)
//or
tagSubject.artworks_subjects.add(artwork)
```

[alt text http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/257/20090902122107.png](http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/257/20090902122107.png)

Is there a common pattern for solving this limitation?

Comment: For some reason, m2m sounds dirty to me... consider just spelling it out ; )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself. For automated relationships to work, both tables need primary keys (oops). Notice artworks_subjects is missing the PK symbol.

Answer (score 5):

the way I have gotten M2M working in LINQ2SQL:

1. drag the tables into the builder,
   like you're showing in the question
2. remove the relationship between
   *artworks_subject* and *artwor*k
3. create a new relationship FROM
   *artworks_subject* TO *artwork*
4. click on the new relationship to get
   its properties
5. change the
   cardinality from OneToMany to
   OneToOne (because ManyToOne doesn't
   exist)
6. open the Child Property
   section and change the Name field to
   make it singular (Artworks to
   Artwork)

now the *tagSubject* entity will have a collection of *artwork_subjects*, and the *artwork_subject* will have a property of type *artwork* called *Artwork*.  so you can now make a LINQ expression like

```
var x = dbcontext.tagSubjects.Single(s=>s.name=="Landscape").
    Artwork_Subjects.
    Select(as=>as.Artwork.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

This largely depends on what framework you are using. It *sounds* like you are using LINQ-to-SQL, which is **very** literal about tables to objects. With Entity Framework, there is inbuilt support for many-to-many, in particular for the trivial case you've listed (a linking table with no additional properties). EF will generally spot this pattern, and hide the link table from the conceptual model (I can't remember, but it might need a spanning PK over the two FK columns).

Of course, this then goes sour if you want to add columns to the link-table; so in some ways I'd be tempted to leave it "as is".

With regards the `where` etc - how do you mean? You can do joins over the association, and you should be able to use `Any` etc; do you have a concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: pretty much exactly what I showed.  The goal is to add a tag to the artwork object.  The only reasonable join is Many to Many.  The only way I've seen so fart to do it with LINQ-to-SQL is to run a loop, creating artwork_subject objects, and binding them manually. 

What I find so odd, is that I can't even do an one to many join between the artwork and artwork_subjects tables (same applies to tagSubjects and artwork_subjects).

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Instead of many-to-many use two many-to-one relationships:

```
Subject -*----1- ArtworkSubjectParticipation -1----*- Artwork
```

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what the OP has already got in the screenshot?

Comment: it's the inverse of what I have. but the net result would mean that only one tag could be associated with one artwork, which is not the goal.

Comment: @Marc, the picture on the original post shows RDBMS structure.  The OO structure is different and is many-to-many.

Comment: @Justin, no. With 2 many-to-one associations you can have implicit many-to-many association.