# Linq many to many?

Tags: asp.net, linq

Say I have products and receipts in a many to many relation. Is there any way I can directly query product.receipts or receipt.products and get the Iqueryable without having to reference the join_table at all?

Comment: Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities or Linq to NHibernate or ... ?

Comment: @IainGalloway Just because your answer is C#, doesn't mean the question was C#. Was that really worth the edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Linq-to-SQL.

The answer is "no, but..."

You *can* work with many-many relationships in Linq-to-SQL, but you *do* need to have a separate type representing the junction table.

If you just want to e.g. databind against a child property of a model object you can do something really simple like:-

```
public partial class Order
{
  public IEnumerable<Product> Products
  {
    get { return Order_Details.Select(x => x.Product); }
  }
}
```

[Beware of the select-n-plus-one problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298972/manually-select-related-table-data-select-n-1-problem-linq-to-sql) though if you then want to use that any time you're using a list of Orders.

Also, there's a whole bunch of duplicate questions:-

[LINQ many-to-many relationships: Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366686/linq-many-to-many-relationships-solution)

[How to load Many to many LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79939/how-to-load-many-to-many-linq-query)

[and tons more.](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB354GB354&q=linq+to+SQL+many+to+many+site:stackoverflow.com&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)

Comment: This is the main reason why I moved from L2S to Entity Framework, and then hit a whole bunch of different issues ;)

Comment: Yup :) I generally say that if L2S "will do", go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities and the Entity Framework supports many to many relations.  I know Linq to Sql does not, and I think (not sure) Linq to NHibernate does support many to many. (I know NHibernate supports many-to-many)